# Shell IP ping script with result save

Tags: shell

I need to write a Shell script that takes in parameters a range of IP addresses, ping them and then saves the ping result in log file that show whether each IP ping result.

The script should be called like this :

```
#script IP1 IP2 IP3 ... IPn
```

The result in the log file should look something like this :

```
254.222.222.222 : ECHEC
158.100.100.100 : SUCCESS
140.140.140.140 : SUCCESS
....
```

Comment: Ok, what did you do so far?

Comment: Nothing, i'm not so familiar with shell-scripting..

Comment: Yes, but we don't coding for you. We may help when you have trouble with your code. Start reading here: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/. There are many more ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
for addr in $@
do
    # ping each address, with timeout of 1 sec
    ping -c 1 -W 1 $addr > /dev/null 2>&1

    # read exit status of ping
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && status=OK || status=FAILED

    # write out result
    echo $addr : $status
done
```